# How to manually download Ubuntu Touch Image for Ubuntu emulator?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

When downloading Ubuntu images with the command below:

> ubuntu-emulator create *instance_name*

The download process can be interrupted if you have a weak Internet connection.
Therefore you will have to download it again from the begining.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and navigate to the chache image directory:

> cd ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/

Get the name of the image file which was partially downloaded:

> export IMGFILE=$(ls ubuntu*xz_)

Generate the link and download the file with pause/resume support:

> wget -c http://system-image.ubuntu.com/pool/${IMGFILE//[_]/}

Once downloaded, create a new instance of Ubuntu Touch:

> ubuntu-emulator create *`instance_name`*